# Error en ruta de Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

tengo un formulario el cual es el siguiente:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
        @csrf
        <label for="nombre"> Digita tu nombre </label>
        <input id="nombre" class="form-control" type="text" name="nombre">

        <label for="apellido"> Digita apellido </label>
        <input id="apellido" class="form-control" type="text" name="apellido">
        <br>
        <input class="form-control" type="submit" value="enviar">

    </form>
```

Resulta que tengo la siguiente ruta definida en web.php

```
Route::get('pruebas', 'MessagesController@store');
```

Y el controlador contiene el siguiente metodo:

```
class MessagesController extends Controller
{
     public function store ()
     {
          return 'Procesar el formulario';
     }
}
```

Pero a la hora de ejecutar el boton del submit, resulta que no sucede nada, solamente me manda la misma url con las variables enviadas en metodo get, mi pregunta es ¿que sucece? ¿Por qué no funciona el método en el controlador?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la intención con esa ruta, mostrar el formulario o procesar la información que de ahí llega?

Comment: La intención es solo comprobar que está ingresando al controlador y la ruta de forma correcta, si fuera así retornaria la cadena "Procesar el formulario", como se ve en el método store del controlador

Comment: Por eso amigo, la duda que te expongo viene de que el método store generalmente esta ligado con la acción de aalmacenar y un método create con la acción de mostrar el formulario, por eso mi duda para publicar la respuesta

Comment: Entonces como podría hacer para retornar la cadena "Procesar el formulario" y comprobar que la ruta y controlador funcionan?

Comment: En el action del form debes poner la ruta

Comment: Como la coloco? Disculpa la ignorancia, es que estoy aprendiendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes hacer los siguientes cambios:

Tus rutas deben ser 2:

- Una `GET` que sirva para mostrar el formulario y para este crea en tu controlador un método cuyo nombre sea `create`
- Una `POST` para procesar los datos tentativos que lleguen del `form` para este crea un método cuyo nombre puede ser `store`
- De paso es mas fácil usarlas si les das un nombre

Rutas:

```
Route::get('pruebas', 'MessagesController@create')->name("pruebas.create");
Route::post('pruebas', 'MessagesController@store')->name("pruebas.store");
```

Posterior en tu formulario declara la ruta por medio del *helper* `route` usando el nombre que les dimos

```
<form action="{{ route('pruebas.store') }}" method="POST">
```

Aclaraciones:

- Los nombres de los métodos no son obligatorios así, solo que nos estamos basando en las acciones de un controlador de tipo `Resource` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers
- Idealmente ya que vas a procesar información puedes:

  - Dejar el mismo nombre de ruta
  - Indicar que verbo ocupará cada ruta, esto evitará problemas por usar la misma en ambos casos
- Aunque al momento tu única intención es mostrar un texto del método `store` lo ideal es que tu `form` use el método `POST` en lugar del `GET`

Comment: Oye, para que sirve el name-> que colocaste en las rutas?

Comment: Es un [método](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#named-routes) que nos sirve para darle un nombre a las rutas, así aunque cambies la URL en ellas, como estarías usando el name dado a través de este método en los formularios no tendrías conflictos al tener que estarlos cambiando

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!